# How to put debug/Breakpoint in Robot framework test in Pycharm?

Tags: robotframework

My .py files in Robot-Framework allows me to introduce breakpoints but .robot file it doesn't allow. How do i introduce and toggle breakpoints in my .robot test files for debugging?

Answer (score 2):

Nohow - you can't add a Pycharm breakpoint in a .robot file.

The reason is your test script is not a real python code. When a run is started, Pycharm runs the entry point of the robot module - which reads the file's text, parses it in its internal structures and "converts" to python code (in quotes, as it really doesn't convert anything, makes RF objects and constructs a flow b/n them).

The actual python code that is ran is in the robotframework package *(and any other py packages & modules it imports)*. For both the framework and Pycharm the .robot file is just a text file - thus no breakpoints are effective.

You can add a breakpoint inside a py file - one of the framework's, or in a library of yours, and it will be honored.
Or, you can use the [Debug library](https://github.com/xyb/robotframework-debuglibrary) - once it hits the point where you've put the `Debug` keyword, it gives you an interactive shell with full context at the current point *(e.g. you can CRUD variables, or run available keywords)*.

Comment: Debug library link returns 404!!

Comment: Love the enthusiasm - here's a working link https://github.com/xyb/robotframework-debuglibrary

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add breakpoints to both .py and **.robot** files with [Robot Framework Language Server](https://github.com/robocorp/robotframework-lsp/tree/master/robotframework-ls).
There are plugins for both [PyCharm](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16086-robot-framework-language-server) and [VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=robocorp.robotframework-lsp).