# Debug .robot file in robot framework pycharm

Tags: python, robotframework

How to run robot file in debug mode in pycharm?

Unable to get debug run option after clicking on right button on robot file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put debug/Breakpoint in Robot framework test in Pycharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68841416/how-to-put-debug-breakpoint-in-robot-framework-test-in-pycharm)

Comment: unable put breakpoint.....